# Beautifulsoup parsing data under specific tag

Tags: html, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, parent-child

Right now I am parsing a web page with this code:

```
boards = soup(itemprop="name")
prices = soup("span", { "class" : "price-currency" })

for board, price in zip(boards, prices):
    print(board.text.strip(), price.next_sibling)
```

And it prints the board and the price like this:

```
SURFBOARD RACK free delivery to your door 120.00
Huge Beginner Surfboard Sale! Kids & Adult Softboards all 1/2 Price!! 90.00
Mega Softboard Clearance Sale! Beginner Foam SurfBoards 1/2 Price! 90.00
Surfboard 6'2" Simon Anderson Spudnick 360.00
Surfboard Cover, Surfboard Bags, Cheap Single Surf Board Bags 50.00
```

The web page that I am parsing is split into 3 sections: sponsored links, top ads, and recent ads.
I am printing data from all 3 of these sections, but want data only from the recent ads section, which has this html:

```
<div class="module__body ad-listing">
```

How do I specify that I only want the  boards and  prices printed from beneath this section?

Page: https://www.gumtree.com.au/s-surfing/mona-vale-sydney/surfboard/k0c18568l3003999r10?fromSearchBox=true

Comment: You wouldn't care to give us the URL for that page, would you? Is it from gumtree?

Comment: @BillBell aha yeh good guess! https://www.gumtree.com.au/s-surfing/mona-vale-sydney/surfboard/k0c18568l3003999r10?fromSearchBox=true

Answer (score 1):

You may detest this answer. My inclination is to use the lxml module when I see complicated HTML like that because I can use xpath expressions.

In this case the first `xpath` finds the collection of `li` elements in the HTML that you want. The loop uses two `xpath` expressions, one that finds stuff like "Quicksale 6'4 Dylan Surfboard RX5" within an `li` element and one that finds the collection of texts for price information within the same element. Item 12 seems to be coded differently; I haven't investigated that.

```
>>> import requests
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> page = requests.get('https://www.gumtree.com.au/s-surfing/mona-vale-sydney/surfboard/k0c18568l3003999r10?fromSearchBox=true').text
>>> parser = etree.HTMLParser()
>>> tree = etree.fromstring(page, parser=parser)
>>> recents = tree.xpath('.//div[@class="module__body ad-listing"]/ul/li')
>>> for i, recent in enumerate(recents):
...     try:
...         i, recent.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="name"]/text()')[0].strip()
...     except:
...         '-------------> item', i, 'failed'
...         continue
...     one_span = first_recent.xpath('.//span[@class="j-original-price"]')[0]
...     ' '.join([_.strip() for _ in list(one_span.itertext()) if _.strip()])
... 
(0, "Quicksale 6'4 Dylan Surfboard RX5")
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(1, 'DHD 5\'9 "Switchblade" Surfboard')
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(2, '6ft Modern Surfboards - Highline')
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(3, "5'11 Channel Island T-Low surfboard")
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(4, 'Chill Rare Bird Surfboard 5"8')
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(5, 'Vintage surfboard')
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(6, "5'7 Annesley Blonde model")
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(7, 'McCoy single fin surfboard')
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(8, 'Sculpt surfboard')
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(9, '8\'1" longboard surfboard travel cover')
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(10, 'Longboard Surfboard')
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(11, "5'10 Custom Chaos Surfboard")
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
('-------------> item', 12, 'failed')
(13, "6'0 JS lowdown")
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(14, 'Mega Softboard Clearance Sale! Beginner Foam SurfBoards 1/2 Price!')
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(15, 'Surfboard')
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(16, 'Surfboard 5\'10" 30 lt')
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(17, 'Christenson Super Sport Surfboard')
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(18, 'TOMO Firewire V4 Surfboard')
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(19, "Surfboard 6'6 baked bean")
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(20, 'foam surfboards')
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(21, 'Channel Islands surfboard')
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(22, 'Channel Islands Surfboard')
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(23, 'JS surfboard')
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(24, 'CLASSIC RETRO SURF FACTORY MINI MAL')
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
(25, 'Surfboard JS')
'$ 450.00 Negotiable'
```